# Widget - Intent stays the same when receiving

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I add contact pictures to a widget dynamical. This is my code for this part:

```
for (int x = 0; x < this.appWidgetIds.length; x++){
        int id = this.appWidgetIds[x];
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(this.context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++){
            String lookupKey = sortedItems.get(i).getLookupKey();
            Tools.ToLog("LOOKUPKEY=" + lookupKey);
            Bitmap bmp = Contact.getContactPicture(this.context, lookupKey);
            if (bmp != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ContactsWidget.class);
                intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
                intent.putExtra(ITENT_LOOKUPKEY, lookupKey);
                Tools.ToLog("LOOKUPKEY - IDENT=" + intent.getStringExtra(ITENT_LOOKUPKEY));

                RemoteViews itemView = new RemoteViews(this.context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_itemview);
                itemView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_ImageView, bmp);
                PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
                itemView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_ImageView, actionPendingIntent);
                rv.addView(R.id.widgetContainer, itemView);
            }
        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, rv);
    }
```

I tested the Lookupkey and the lookupkey from the intent over the log and it works on this side (variable lookupKey == intent.getStringExtra(ITENT_LOOKUPKEY)). When I now receive the intent because I clicked on a contact picture the intent extra info is always the same. No matter which of the contact pictures I clicked. This is the receive code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
        String lookupKey = intent.getStringExtra(ITENT_LOOKUPKEY);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Lookup Key: " + lookupKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Contact.openContact(this.context, lookupKey);             
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

It's always the lookupKey from the first added contact. Do I have to clear the intent somehow before adding another contact in the first function or what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one `PendingIntent`.

Quoting the documentation:

> If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid

Since you have the same operation (`getActivity()`) and the same `Intent` routing pieces each time, there is only one `PendingIntent`.

Rather than setting the action to be `ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER`, make it be unique for each that you are creating in your loops.